# dart analysis_options.yaml behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, lint, analyzer

I have created a dart file with this code :-

[image: code to see dart analyzer tools in VSCode]

Code to see dart analyzer tools in practice.

Now, I have created an `analysis_options.yaml` file to add linting
but after this no `info` is shown :-

[image: no info]

Now, I know I could add `empty_statements: info` in `analysis_options.yaml`.
But why did it suppress the default `info`.
If this happens to some other info or warnings, one could not know it because it will get suppressed.
For example if I add this line (without changing anything in analysis_options.yaml):-

[image: close_sinks]

As we can see no `info` is shown.
But had there been no `analysis_options.yaml` file this is shown :-

[image: last]

So, should I write each and every lint [from here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) ?
Why are the default info/warnings suppressed ?

Comment: What does your analysis_options.yaml contain? Is it empty?

Comment: Yes, right now its empty. But the point is why are the default static analyzers are being suppressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using this [lint package](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) as a dev dependency, then your `analysis_options.yaml` file should contain this line at the top:

```
include: package:lint/analysis_options.yaml
```

**Edit:**
And as to the why enabling this, other rules are suppressed.. I assume it is because of this:

> ... only 27/150+ rules to be enabled. While some are contradictory to
> each other and can not enabled together, a big chunk of rules isn't
> enabled because it requires too much work to update all of Googles
> existing code.
>
> For developers outside Google, it is the norm to have
> separate lint rules per project. One project might enable more rules
> then others."

Comment: Yes, so by doing this some linters will work again, but why are the original ones gone. For ex - this package does not include `close_sinks` linter. How come one can know about that if original ones are gone.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I assume that it is because of this text: "... only 27/150+ rules to be enabled. While some are contradictory to each other and can not enabled together, a big chunk of rules isn't enabled because it requires too much work to update all of Googles existing code. For developers outside Google, it is the norm to have separate lint rules per project. One project might enable more rules then others."

Comment: @PriyanshuGupta when it comes to your specific wonder about close_sinks, that is because the flutter team has deemed it not reliable enough. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4d6a925326c08d0fa2fcf9bf3cdc669d290868c7/analysis_options.yaml#L102

Comment: So, like the default `lints` are coming from the flutter sdk ?

Comment: No the default comes from Dart. Read all about it at: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options